# Standalone tikz & Remember picture: not working when scaled

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, remember

When I scale my `\includestandalone[width=...]`, my remembered coordinate (A) is not at the right position anymore.
How can I fix that?

A.tex: a standalone tikz that defines the coordinate (A) at the center

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-a}};
      \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Main.tex: include the standalone and draw a circle at (A)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \includestandalone[width=5cm]{A}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[red] (A) circle(1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The circle is not centered on (A)!
[image]

How to keep the circle centred on (A), even if the standalone is scaled?

Answer (score 1):

The example works if the option `[width=5cm]` is given to `\includegraphics` in the file `A.tex` instead of `\includestandalone` in the file `Main.tex`.

According to the pgfmanual, the syntax `\draw[red] (A) circle(1);` is old. The newer syntax is `\draw[red] (A) circle [radius=1];`.

[image]

File A.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
      \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
      \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

File Main.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \includestandalone{A}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[red] (A) circle [radius=1];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer (and the syntax advise :-). This already an excellent solution, but ... the idea is to externalise the tikz to re-use it in a beamer doc. I am not sure that setting the dimension in the standalone will suit all my use cases.

Comment: I would love to get @MartinScharrer's reaction on this ...

Comment: @JosephMarie The width can be defined depending on whether externalization is used. For example `width=\mywidth` where `\mywidth` can be defined in the preamble.

Comment: Of course, this is a way. But to be honest, I won't push this style of making my standalone code dependant of a 'global' variable.